# how to get the non common record from one table using only join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, emp, dept

```
emp
empno ename
1     10
2     20

dept
deptno dname
10     A
20     B
30     C
```

I want to get the result only with the joins condition, not with subquery. I am able to get it with subquery, please assist.

```
Result
deptno dname
30     C
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your working subquery version. And tell us why you don't want it.

Comment: BTW, your table are unrelated, your task makes no sense at all. _Give me the departments having a non-employee department no._

Comment: A subquery will still perform a join - what's the problem with a subquery? The query optimizer does not necessarily execute a query verbatim for how it's written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nothing but a left outer join while filtering empno IS NULL such as

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM dept d
  LEFT JOIN emp e
    ON deptno = ename
 WHERE empno IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, i already found the answer but didn't know how to select only the required columns, my code is
Select *
FROM b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.b=b.b where a.a is null;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.deptno, d.dname
FROM dept d
LEFT JOIN emp e ON d.deptno = e.ename
WHERE e.empno IS NULL;
```